# MongoDB connection with python with ServerSelectionTimeoutError Issue

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect MongoDB database with python but I don't have access to MongoDB database since xxx don't give access to us..I know Hostname,username,password and port Number. when I am trying to run a query from python to access data . I am getting serverselection timeout error.

```py
Connectionstring="mongodb://username:password@hostname:portnumber/"
Mongoclient=pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string).
```

I am getting error here

```py
print(Mongoclient.list_database_names())
```

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: Got response id 540160302 but expected 8723, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6362a1c9ecd5ada84257e071, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('Hostname',Port) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=ProtocolError('Got response id 540160302 but expected 8723')>]>
```

I searched but  since I don't have an access to the database I don't know whether by using connection string my issue will be resolved. I even used this code

```
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
client = Mongoclient
try:
    # The ping command is cheap and does not require auth.
    client.admin.command('ping')
except ConnectionFailure:
    print("Server not available")
```

The code prints out `Server not available`. I don't how to proceed with this issue. I also used `connect=False` in the parameter of `MongoClient(connectionstring,connect=False)` but this also didn't work.

Comment: _"but I don't have access to MongoDB database"_ ... What do you mean by that?  It's possible for the server to block requests from unknown IP addresses.  There are numerous other ways and reasons that the database may be denied to you.  If you _"don't have access"_, should you really be trying to access it?

Comment: We can't directly go to the MongoDB Database and access it. Only they provide us hostname,username,password and port number to access the database

Comment: I notice that `Connectionstring` and `connection_string` are not the same.  Has there been a typo somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the Printing in Stackoverflow but in my jupyter notebook connection_string I have used everywhere

Comment: You can edit your question to fix any errors and/or provide more information.